# Counting non NAs in a data frame; getting answer as a vector

Tags: r, na

Say I have the following R *data.frame* `ZZZ`:

```
( ZZZ <- structure(list(n = c(1, 2, NA), m = c(6, NA, NA), o = c(7, 8, 
8)), .Names = c("n", "m", "o"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame") )

## not run
   n  m o
1  1  6 7
2  2 NA 8
3 NA NA 8
```

I want to know, in the form of a vector, how many non-NAs I've got. I want the answer available to me as:

```
2, 1, 3
```

When I use the command `length(ZZZ)`, I get `3`, which of course is the number of vectors in the *data.frame*, a valuable enough piece of information.

I have other functions that operate on this *data.frame* and give me answers in the form of vectors, but, dang-it, length doesn't operate like that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
# define "demo" dataset
ZZZ <- data.frame(n=c(1,2,NA),m=c(6,NA,NA),o=c(7,8,8))
# apply the counting function per columns
apply(ZZZ, 2, function(x) length(which(!is.na(x))))
```

Having run:

```
> apply(ZZZ, 2, function(x) length(which(!is.na(x))))
n m o 
2 1 3
```

If you really insist on returning a vector, you might use `as.vector`, e.g. by defining this function:

```
nonNAs <- function(x) {
    as.vector(apply(x, 2, function(x) length(which(!is.na(x)))))
    }
```

You could simply run `nonNAs(ZZZ)`:

```
> nonNAs(ZZZ)
[1] 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 100):

```
colSums(!is.na(x))
```

Vectorisation ftw.

Comment: Might be instead (based on OP): `colSums(!is.na(x))` But anyway: +1 goes to your nice soultion.

Comment: IMHO your solution should be the preferred one

Comment: This is much faster than the chosen answer!

Answer (score 7):

For getting total no of missing values use sum(is.na(x)) and for colum-wise use colSums(is.na(x)) where x is varible that contain dataset

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the sum total of NAs overall, then sum() with !is.na() will do it:

```
ZZZ <- data.frame(n = c(1, 2, NA), m = c(6, NA, NA), o = c(7, 8, 8))
sum(!is.na(ZZZ))
```

Comment: I think the OP is after the number of NAs **per** column in the data frame not in overall.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help on this. It answers my question. I am only just beginning to open the door to see what R can do. It is truly an amazing tool.