# Is the "*apply" family really not vectorized?

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization, apply

So we are used to say to every R new user that "*`apply` isn't vectorized, check out the Patrick Burns [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) Circle 4*" which says (I quote):

> A common reflex is to use a function in the apply family. **This is not**
>   **vectorization, it is loop-hiding**. The apply function has a for loop in
>   its definition. The lapply function buries the loop, but execution
>   times tend to be roughly equal to an explicit for loop.

Indeed, a quick look on the `apply` source code reveals the loop:

```
grep("for", capture.output(getAnywhere("apply")), value = TRUE)
## [1] "        for (i in 1L:d2) {"  "    else for (i in 1L:d2) {"
```

Ok so far, but a look at `lapply` or `vapply` actually reveals a completely different picture:

```
lapply
## function (X, FUN, ...) 
## {
##     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
##     if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
##        X <- as.list(X)
##     .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
## }
## <bytecode: 0x000000000284b618>
## <environment: namespace:base>
```

So apparently there is no R `for` loop hiding there, rather they are calling internal C written function.

A quick look in the [rabbit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c#L627-L630) [hole](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/apply.c#L34) reveals pretty much the same picture

Moreover, let's take the `colMeans` function for example, which was never accused in not being vectorised

```
colMeans
# function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L) 
# {
#   if (is.data.frame(x)) 
#     x <- as.matrix(x)
#   if (!is.array(x) || length(dn <- dim(x)) < 2L) 
#     stop("'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions")
#   if (dims < 1L || dims > length(dn) - 1L) 
#     stop("invalid 'dims'")
#   n <- prod(dn[1L:dims])
#   dn <- dn[-(1L:dims)]
#   z <- if (is.complex(x)) 
#     .Internal(colMeans(Re(x), n, prod(dn), na.rm)) + (0+1i) * 
#     .Internal(colMeans(Im(x), n, prod(dn), na.rm))
#   else .Internal(colMeans(x, n, prod(dn), na.rm))
#   if (length(dn) > 1L) {
#     dim(z) <- dn
#     dimnames(z) <- dimnames(x)[-(1L:dims)]
#   }
#   else names(z) <- dimnames(x)[[dims + 1]]
#   z
# }
# <bytecode: 0x0000000008f89d20>
#   <environment: namespace:base>
```

Huh? It also just calls `.Internal(colMeans(...` which we can also find in the [rabbit hole](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c#L731). So how is this different from `.Internal(lapply(..`?

Actually a quick benchmark reveals that `sapply` performs no worse than `colMeans` and much better than a `for` loop for a big data set

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:1e7, ncol = 1e5))
system.time(colMeans(m))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.69    0.03    1.73 
system.time(sapply(m, mean))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.50    0.03    1.60 
system.time(apply(m, 2, mean))
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.84    0.03    3.90 
system.time(for(i in 1:ncol(m)) mean(m[, i]))
# user  system elapsed 
# 13.78    0.01   13.93
```

In other words, is it correct to say that `lapply` and `vapply` **are actually vectorised** (compared to `apply` which is a `for` loop that also calls `lapply`) and what did Patrick Burns really mean to say?

Comment: This is all in the semantics, but I wouldn't consider them vectorized. I consider an approach vectorized if an R function is called only once and can be passed a vector of values. `*apply` functions repeatedly call R functions, which makes them loops. Regarding the good performance of `sapply(m, mean)`: Possibly the C-code of `lapply` does method dispatch only once and then calls the method repeatedly? `mean.default` is pretty optimized.

Comment: Excellent question, and thanks for checking the underlying code. I was looking if it has been recently changed, but nothing about this in R release notes from version 2.13.0 onward.

Comment: (+1) I wanted to ask the same question. What about `vapply` example? On my PC it gets even faster then `colMeans`.

Comment: To what extent does the performance depend on both the platform and the C-compiler and linker flags used?

Comment: I think this question is meaningless until you define precisely what you mean by "vectorized".

Comment: @eriatarka84 actually "vectorized" is pretty much well defined among the ordinary R users, see [here](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) for example.

Comment: I agree with @Roland's assessment. `*apply` functions repeatedly evaluate R functions, so I wouldn't consider them vectorized. And `lapply` doesn't only do method dispatch once. That wouldn't work because list elements don't have to be homogeneous (e.g. `lapply(list(1:5,1:5*1), sum)` wouldn't work).

Comment: @DavidArenburg Actually, I don't think it is well defined. At least I don't know a canonical reference. The language definition mentions "vectorized" operations, but doesn't define vectorization.

Comment: Very related: [Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/903061) (And, like these answers, also a good read.)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First of all, in your example you make tests on a "data.frame" which is not fair for `colMeans`, `apply` and `"[.data.frame"` since they have an overhead:

```
system.time(as.matrix(m))  #called by `colMeans` and `apply`
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.03    0.00    1.05
system.time(for(i in 1:ncol(m)) m[, i])  #in the `for` loop
#   user  system elapsed 
#  12.93    0.01   13.07
```

On a matrix, the picture is a bit different:

```
mm = as.matrix(m)
system.time(colMeans(mm))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.00    0.01 
system.time(apply(mm, 2, mean))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.48    0.03    1.53 
system.time(for(i in 1:ncol(mm)) mean(mm[, i]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.22    0.00    1.21
```

Regading the main part of the question, the main difference between `lapply`/`mapply`/etc and straightforward R-loops is where the looping is done. As Roland notes, both C and R loops need to evaluate an R function in each iteration which is the most costly. The really fast C functions are those that do everything in C, so, I guess, this should be what "vectorised" is about?

An example where we find the mean in each of a "list"s elements:

*(**EDIT May 11 '16** : I believe the example with finding the "mean" is not a good setup for the differences between evaluating an R function iteratively and compiled code, (1) because of the particularity of R's mean algorithm on "numeric"s over a simple `sum(x) / length(x)` and (2) it should make more sense to test on "list"s with `length(x) >> lengths(x)`. So, the "mean" example is moved to the end and replaced with another.)*

As a simple example we could consider the finding of the opposite of each `length == 1` element of a "list":

In a `tmp.c` file:

```
#include <R.h>
#define USE_RINTERNALS 
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

/* call a C function inside another */
double oppC(double x) { return(ISNAN(x) ? NA_REAL : -x); }
SEXP sapply_oppC(SEXP x)
{
    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(x)));
    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(x); i++) 
        REAL(ans)[i] = oppC(REAL(VECTOR_ELT(x, i))[0]);

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
}

/* call an R function inside a C function;
 * will be used with 'f' as a closure and as a builtin */    
SEXP sapply_oppR(SEXP x, SEXP f)
{
    SEXP call = PROTECT(allocVector(LANGSXP, 2));
    SETCAR(call, install(CHAR(STRING_ELT(f, 0))));

    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(x)));     
    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(x); i++) { 
        SETCADR(call, VECTOR_ELT(x, i));
        REAL(ans)[i] = REAL(eval(call, R_GlobalEnv))[0];
    }

    UNPROTECT(2);
    return(ans);
}
```

And in R side:

```
system("R CMD SHLIB /home/~/tmp.c")
dyn.load("/home/~/tmp.so")
```

with data:

```
set.seed(007)
myls = rep_len(as.list(c(NA, runif(3))), 1e7)

#a closure wrapper of `-`
oppR = function(x) -x

for_oppR = compiler::cmpfun(function(x, f)
{
    f = match.fun(f)  
    ans = numeric(length(x))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) ans[[i]] = f(x[[i]])
    return(ans)
})
```

Benchmarking:

```
#call a C function iteratively
system.time({ sapplyC =  .Call("sapply_oppC", myls) }) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.048   0.000   0.047 

#evaluate an R closure iteratively
system.time({ sapplyRC =  .Call("sapply_oppR", myls, "oppR") }) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.348   0.000   3.358 

#evaluate an R builtin iteratively
system.time({ sapplyRCprim =  .Call("sapply_oppR", myls, "-") }) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.652   0.000   0.653 

#loop with a R closure
system.time({ forR = for_oppR(myls, "oppR") })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.396   0.000   4.409 

#loop with an R builtin
system.time({ forRprim = for_oppR(myls, "-") })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.908   0.000   1.913 

#for reference and testing 
system.time({ sapplyR = unlist(lapply(myls, oppR)) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.080   0.068   7.170 
system.time({ sapplyRprim = unlist(lapply(myls, `-`)) }) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.524   0.064   3.598 

all.equal(sapplyR, sapplyRprim)
#[1] TRUE 
all.equal(sapplyR, sapplyC)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(sapplyR, sapplyRC)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(sapplyR, sapplyRCprim)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(sapplyR, forR)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(sapplyR, forRprim)
#[1] TRUE
```

*(Follows the original example of mean finding):*

```
#all computations in C
all_C = inline::cfunction(sig = c(R_ls = "list"), body = '
    SEXP tmp, ans;
    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(R_ls)));

    double *ptmp, *pans = REAL(ans);

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(R_ls); i++) {
        pans[i] = 0.0;

        PROTECT(tmp = coerceVector(VECTOR_ELT(R_ls, i), REALSXP));
        ptmp = REAL(tmp);

        for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH(tmp); j++) pans[i] += ptmp[j];

        pans[i] /= LENGTH(tmp);

        UNPROTECT(1);
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
')

#a very simple `lapply(x, mean)`
C_and_R = inline::cfunction(sig = c(R_ls = "list"), body = '
    SEXP call, ans, ret;

    PROTECT(call = allocList(2));
    SET_TYPEOF(call, LANGSXP);
    SETCAR(call, install("mean"));

    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(VECSXP, LENGTH(R_ls)));
    PROTECT(ret = allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(ans)));

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(R_ls); i++) {
        SETCADR(call, VECTOR_ELT(R_ls, i));
        SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, i, eval(call, R_GlobalEnv));
    }

    double *pret = REAL(ret);
    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(ans); i++) pret[i] = REAL(VECTOR_ELT(ans, i))[0];

    UNPROTECT(3);
    return(ret);
')                    

R_lapply = function(x) unlist(lapply(x, mean))                       

R_loop = function(x) 
{
    ans = numeric(length(x))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) ans[i] = mean(x[[i]])
    return(ans)
} 

R_loopcmp = compiler::cmpfun(R_loop)


set.seed(007); myls = replicate(1e4, runif(1e3), simplify = FALSE)
all.equal(all_C(myls), C_and_R(myls))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(all_C(myls), R_lapply(myls))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(all_C(myls), R_loop(myls))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(all_C(myls), R_loopcmp(myls))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(all_C(myls), 
                               C_and_R(myls), 
                               R_lapply(myls), 
                               R_loop(myls), 
                               R_loopcmp(myls), 
                               times = 15)
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#     all_C(myls)  37.29183  38.19107  38.69359  39.58083  41.3861    15
#   C_and_R(myls) 117.21457 123.22044 124.58148 130.85513 169.6822    15
#  R_lapply(myls)  98.48009 103.80717 106.55519 109.54890 116.3150    15
#    R_loop(myls) 122.40367 130.85061 132.61378 138.53664 178.5128    15
# R_loopcmp(myls) 105.63228 111.38340 112.16781 115.68909 128.1976    15
```

Comment: Great point about the costs of converting the data.frame to a matrix, and thanks for providing benchmarks.

Comment: That is a very nice answer, though I wasn't able to compile your `all_C` and `C_and_R` functions. I also found in the documentations of `compiler::cmpfun` an *old R version of lapply* which contains an actual R `for` loop, I'm starting to suspect that Burns was referring to *that* old version which was vectorised since then and this is the actual answer to my question....

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Benchmarking `la1` from `?compiler::cmpfun` seems, still, to yield same efficiency with all but `all_C` functions. I guess, it -indeed- comes to be a matter of definition; is "vectorised" meaning any function that accepts not only scalars, any function that has C code, any function that uses computations in C only?

Comment: I guess *all* functions in R have C code in them, simply because *everything* in R is a function (which had to be written in some language). So basically, if I understand it right, you are saying that `lapply` isn't vectorized simply because it's evaluating an R function in *each* iteration wihin its C code?

Comment: Ok, I've summed everything up and posted as an answer that easier to understand and addresses the specific question if `lapply` is vectorized or not. Thanks for this great answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : If I must define "vectorization" in some way, I guess, I would choose a linguistic approach; i.e. a function that accepts and knows how to handle a "vector", whether it's fast, slow, written in C, in R or anything else. In R, the importance of vectorisation is in that many functions are written in C and handle vectors while in other languages users would , usually, loop over the input to -e.g.- find the mean. That makes vectorisation to relate, indirectly, with speed, efficiency, safety, and robustness.

Answer (score 67):

To me, vectorisation is primarily about making your code easier to write and easier to understand.

The goal of a vectorised function is to eliminate the book-keeping associated with a for loop. For example, instead of:

```
means <- numeric(length(mtcars))
for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  means[i] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
}
sds <- numeric(length(mtcars))
for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  sds[i] <- sd(mtcars[[i]])
}
```

You can write:

```
means <- vapply(mtcars, mean, numeric(1))
sds   <- vapply(mtcars, sd, numeric(1))
```

That makes it easier to see what's the same (the input data) and what's different (the function you're applying).

A secondary advantage of vectorisation is that the for-loop is often written in C, rather than in R. This has substantial performance benefits, but I don't think it's the key property of vectorisation. Vectorisation is fundamentally about saving your brain, not saving the computer work.

Comment: I don't think there is a meaningful performance difference between C and R `for` loops. OK, a C loop might be optimized by the compiler, but the main point for performance is whether the content of the loop is efficient. And obviously compiled code is usually faster than interpreted code. But that's probably what you meant to say.

Comment: @Roland yeah, it's not the for-loop itself per se, it's all the stuff around it (the cost of a function call, the ability to modify in place, ...).

Comment: So by your definition of vectorisation even `apply(m, 2, sum)` is vectorized. Which seems a bit inconsistent with Burns definition, the general consensus or even your [old answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986101/counting-non-nas-in-a-data-frame-getting-answer-as-a-vector/4986269#4986269)

Comment: @DavidArenburg "Needless consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds" ;)

Comment: I'm still struggling with your "*Vectorisation is fundamentally about saving your brain, not saving the computer work*". If I, for example vectorise my code using C functions only (that are not calling an R function, like `lapply` does) and my performance improves by factor of ten, is it the whole point of vectorizing the code? Isn't that the whole point you and Roman rewritten `plyr` (which was a R wrapper) to `dplyr` (which is completely written in C++, beside the point that you wanted that every operation will have its own function)? Isn't this the point of `Rcpp` and `data.table` packages?

Comment: No, I don't think performance is the main point of vectorising your code. Rewriting a loop into an lapply is beneficial even if it isn't any faster. The main point of dplyr is that it makes it easier to express data manipulation (and it's just very nice that it's also fast).

Comment: But why to write a loop in a first place? Why not vectorise it straight away? I can't remember when I last wrote a loop although working with R whole day. The only reason to write a loop as I see it, is if you need to update some vector depending on the previous iteration. But this type of a loop will look ugly within `lapply` frame work too, as you will have to write a custom function. Unless you saying that there are some operations that can't be done without either `lapply` or a `for` loop, but then again, this is why we have `Rcpp` for. You also use it extensively for that purpose.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that's because you're an experienced R user. Most new users find loops much more natural, and need to be encouraged to vectorise. To me, using a function like colMeans isn't necessarily about vectorisation, it's about reusing fast code that someone has already written

Comment: You could define vectorisation as loops in C vs. loops in R, but I don't think that's as helpful a definition for most R users

Comment: Actually this is not how I defined vectorization in my answer (though once I was defining it this way) but I see where you going. Though I still won't consider `lapply` vectorized only because it is easy to use. I wonder who defined this concept in the first place. Because it seems like Burns defined it similarly to how I understand it (first two loop types are *not* vectorized).

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't think that's a terribly useful breakdown. It's just an observation that calling an R function is much more expensive than calling a C function.

Comment: Not precisely, because calling R function once could be considered vectorized (from my point of view at least), maybe similarly to what `do.call` does, but evaluating a R function within *each* iteration of a loop (no matter if its C or R) seems like a very bad practice, that should be avoided by vectorised functions if possible.

Answer (score 52):

I agree with Patrick Burns' view that it is rather *loop hiding* and not *code vectorisation*. Here's why:

Consider this `C` code snippet:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
```

*What* we would like to do is quite clear. But *how* the task is performed or how it could be performed isn't really. A *for-loop* by default is a serial construct. It doesn't inform if or how things can be done in parallel.

The most obvious way is that the code is run in a *sequential manner*. Load `a[i]` and `b[i]` on to registers, add them, store the result in `c[i]`, and do this for each `i`.

However, modern processors have [*vector* or *SIMD*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instruction set which is capable of operating on a *vector of data* during the *same instruction* when performing the same operation (e.g., adding two vectors as shown above). Depending on the processor/architecture, it might be possible to add, say, four numbers from `a` and `b` under the same instruction, instead of one at a time.

> We would like to exploit the [*Single Instruction Multiple Data*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) and perform *data level parallelism*, i.e., load 4 things at a time, add 4 things at time, store 4 things at a time, for example. And this is *code vectorisation*.
>
> Note that this is different from code parallelisation -- where multiple computations are performed concurrently.

It'd be great if the compiler identifies such blocks of code and *automatically* vectorises them, which is a difficult task. [*Automatic code vectorisation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) is a challenging research topic in Computer Science. But over time, compilers have gotten better at it. You can check the *auto vectorisation* capabilities of `GNU-gcc` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#vectorizab). Similarly for `LLVM-clang` [here](http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html). And you can also find some benchmarks in the last link compared against `gcc` and `ICC` (Intel C++ compiler).

`gcc` (I'm on `v4.9`) for example doesn't vectorise code automatically at `-O2` level optimisation. So if we were to execute the code shown above, it'd be run sequentially. Here's the timing for adding two integer vectors of length 500 million.

We either need to add the flag `-ftree-vectorize` or change optimisation to level `-O3`. (Note that `-O3` performs [other additional optimisations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) as well). The flag [`-fopt-info-vec`](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LHCb/VectorizeSource-code) is useful as it informs when a loop was successfully vectorised).

```
# compiling with -O2, -ftree-vectorize and  -fopt-info-vec
# test.c:32:5: note: loop vectorized
# test.c:32:5: note: loop versioned for vectorization because of possible aliasing
# test.c:32:5: note: loop peeled for vectorization to enhance alignment
```

This tells us that the function is vectorised. Here are the timings comparing both non-vectorised and vectorised versions on integer vectors of length 500 million:

```
x = sample(100L, 500e6L, TRUE)
y = sample(100L, 500e6L, TRUE)
z = vector("integer", 500e6L) # result vector

# non-vectorised, -O2
system.time(.Call("Csum", x, y, z))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.830   0.009   1.852

# vectorised using flags shown above at -O2
system.time(.Call("Csum", x, y, z))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.361   0.001   0.362

# both results are checked for identicalness, returns TRUE
```

---

This part can be safely skipped without losing continuity.

Compilers will not always have sufficient information to vectorise. We could use [OpenMP specification for parallel programming](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/), which also provides a *simd* compiler directive to instruct compilers to vectorise the code. It is essential to ensure that there are no memory overlaps, race conditions etc.. when vectorising code manually, else it'll result in incorrect results.

```
#pragma omp simd
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
```

By doing this, we specifically ask the compiler to vectorise it no matter what. We'll need to activate OpenMP extensions by using compile time flag [`-fopenmp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html). By doing that:

```
# timing with -O2 + OpenMP with simd
x = sample(100L, 500e6L, TRUE)
y = sample(100L, 500e6L, TRUE)
z = vector("integer", 500e6L) # result vector
system.time(.Call("Cvecsum", x, y, z))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.360   0.001   0.360
```

which is great! This was tested with gcc v6.2.0 and llvm clang v3.9.0 (both installed via homebrew, MacOS 10.12.3), both of which support OpenMP 4.0.

---

In this sense, even though [Wikipedia page on Array Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) mentions that languages that operate on entire arrays usually call that as *vectorised operations*, it really is *loop hiding* IMO (unless it is actually vectorised).

In case of R, even `rowSums()` or `colSums()` code in C don't exploit *code vectorisation* IIUC; it is just a loop in C. Same goes for `lapply()`. In case of `apply()`, it's in R. All of these are therefore *loop hiding*.

> In short, wrapping an R function by:
>
> just writing a *for-loop* in `C` != vectorising your code.
> just writing a *for-loop* in `R` != vectorising your code.
>
> [Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL)](http://www.polyhedron.com/web_images/documents/An_Introduction_to_Vectorization_with_Intel_Fortran_Compiler_021712.pdf) for example implements vectorised forms of functions.

HTH

---

References:

1. [Talk by James Reinders, Intel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyZMssi_gZY) (this answer is mostly an attempt to summarise this excellent talk)

Answer (score 38):

So to sum the great answers/comments up into some general answer and provide some background: R has 4 types of loops (**in from not-vectorized to vectorized order**)

1. R `for` loop that repeatedly calls R functions in each iterations (**Not vectorised**)
2. C loop that repeatedly calls R functions in each iterations (**Not vectorised**)
3. C loop that calls R function only once (**Somewhat vectorized**)
4. A plain C loop that doesn't call *any* R function at all and uses it own compiled functions (**Vectorized**)

**So the `*apply` family is the second type. Except `apply` which is more of the first type**

You can understand this from the comment in its [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/apply.c#L27-L33)

> /* .Internal(lapply(X, FUN)) */
>
> /* This is a special .Internal, so has unevaluated arguments.  It is
>   called from a closure wrapper, so X and FUN are promises.    FUN must
>   be unevaluated for use in e.g. bquote .
>   */

That means that `lapply`s C code accepts an unevaluated function from R and later evaluates it within the C code itself. This is basically the difference between `lapply`s `.Internal` call

```
.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
```

Which has a `FUN` argument that holds an R function

And the `colMeans` `.Internal` call which *does not* have a `FUN` argument

```
.Internal(colMeans(Re(x), n, prod(dn), na.rm))
```

`colMeans`, unlike `lapply` knows *exactly* what function it needs to use, thus it calculates the mean internally within the C code.

You can clearly see the evaluation process of the R function in each iteration within [`lapply` C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/apply.c#L72-L78)

```
 for(R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (realIndx) REAL(ind)[0] = (double)(i + 1);
      else INTEGER(ind)[0] = (int)(i + 1);
      tmp = eval(R_fcall, rho);   // <----------------------------- here it is
      if (MAYBE_REFERENCED(tmp)) tmp = lazy_duplicate(tmp);
      SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, i, tmp);
   }
```

---

To sum things up, **`lapply` is not vectorized**, though it has two possible advantages over the plain R `for` loop

1. Accessing and assigning in a loop seems to be faster in C (i.e. in `lapply`ing a function) Although the difference seems big, we, still, stay at the microsecond level and the costly thing is the valuation of an R function in each iteration. A simple example:

   ```
   ffR = function(x)  {
       ans = vector("list", length(x))
       for(i in seq_along(x)) ans[[i]] = x[[i]]
       ans 
   }

   ffC = inline::cfunction(sig = c(R_x = "data.frame"), body = '
       SEXP ans;
       PROTECT(ans = allocVector(VECSXP, LENGTH(R_x)));
       for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(R_x); i++) 
              SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, i, VECTOR_ELT(R_x, i));
       UNPROTECT(1);
       return(ans); 
   ')

   set.seed(007) 
   myls = replicate(1e3, runif(1e3), simplify = FALSE)     
   mydf = as.data.frame(myls)

   all.equal(ffR(myls), ffC(myls))
   #[1] TRUE 
   all.equal(ffR(mydf), ffC(mydf))
   #[1] TRUE

   microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ffR(myls), ffC(myls), 
                                  ffR(mydf), ffC(mydf),
                                  times = 30)
   #Unit: microseconds
   #      expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
   # ffR(myls)  3933.764  3975.076  4073.540  5121.045 32956.580    30
   # ffC(myls)    12.553    12.934    16.695    18.210    19.481    30
   # ffR(mydf) 14799.340 15095.677 15661.889 16129.689 18439.908    30
   # ffC(mydf)    12.599    13.068    15.835    18.402    20.509    30
   ```
2. As mentioned by @Roland, it runs a compiled C loop rather an interpreted R loop

---

Though when vectorizing your code, there are some things you need to take into account.

1. If your data set (let's call it `df`) is of class `data.frame`, some vectorized functions (such as `colMeans`, `colSums`, `rowSums`, etc.) will have to convert it to a matrix first, simply because this is how they were designed. This means that for a big `df` this can create a huge overhead. While `lapply` won't have to do this as it extracts the actual vectors out of `df` (as `data.frame` is just a list of vectors) and thus, if you have not so many columns but many rows, `lapply(df, mean)` can sometimes be better option than `colMeans(df)`.
2. Another thing to remember is that R has a great variety of different function types, such as `.Primitive`, and generic (`S3`, `S4`) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) for some additional information. The generic function have to do a method dispatch which sometimes a costly operation. For example, `mean` is generic `S3` function while `sum` is `Primitive`. Thus some times `lapply(df, sum)` could be very efficient compared `colSums` from the reasons listed above

Comment: Very cohesive summary. Just a few notes: (1) C knows how to handle "data.frame"s, since they are "list"s with attributes; it's that `colMeans` etc. that are built to handle only matrices. (2) I'm a bit confused by your third category; I can't tell what -exaclty- you're referring to. (3) Since you're referring specifically to `lapply`, I believe it doesn't make a difference between `"[<-"` in R and C; they both pre-allocate a "list" (an SEXP) and fill it in each iteration (`SET_VECTOR_ELT` in C), unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: (1) Fair enough, my C skills are pathetic, so I'll fix this. Re (2) I'm not entirely sure myself, I was under the impression that this is how `do.call` and similar functions work, though I may be wrong (see my comment re my C skills above). (3) I do believe there is a difference, because R has to call ````[<-```` in each iteration which I believe is less costly when done in C as in C it is not a separate function, isn't it? Not to mention if you need to call ````[.data.frame```` in each iteration (like you already mentioned). Either way you may edit my answer at will if you feel I'm wrong.

Comment: I get your point about `do.call` in that it builts a function call in the C environmen and just evaluates it; although I'm having a hard time to compare it to looping or vectorization since it does a different thing. You're, actually, right about accessing and assigning differences between C and R, although both stay at the microsecond level and don't affect the result the rerult hugely, since the costly is the iterative R function call (compare `R_loop` and `R_lapply` in my answer). (I'll edit your post with a benchmark; I hope you, still, won't mind)

Comment: I think it's beneficial to acknowledge that there is a user-interface dimension to vectorization---even if it's more-or-less orthogonal to the implementation. I can write wrap an R function in an R `for` loop (or use `base::Vectorize`) and it may still score a 0 in any vectorization-implemented-for-optimization metric, but it from a UI perspective if the wrapped version takes a vector argument where the original didn't, *it is vectorized*.

Comment: @Gregor this is basically what hadley says and I completely disagree. As you can see, Burns also stricly says "*This is not vectorization, it is loop-hiding*" and I explicitly asked what did he mean by that. I think even hadley understands that `apply` is nothing more than some lame syntactic sugar (like the question you yourself linked) and hence while writing `dplyr` (unlike when writing `plyr` he invested most of his effort in optimization of the code using the `Rcpp` package).

Comment: I'm not trying to disagree---and I'm confused, honestly, about what you're disagreeing with. My earlier comment could have been worded better. I'm trying refine the terminology being used because the term "vectorization" has two definitions that are often conflated. I don't think this is arguable. Burns and you seem to want to use it only in the sense of implementation, but Hadley and many R-Core members (taking `Vectorize()` as an example) use it in the UI sense too. I think that much of the disagreement in this thread is caused by using one term for two separate-but-related concepts.

Comment: @Gregor I think the R-Core team named `Vectorize()` not in the user-interface sense, they only meant that if you have a function that works only on a scalar (vector of length 1), you can make it to work on a whole *vector* (vector of length > 1) - hence the name.

Comment: @DavidArenburg and is that not vectorization in a UI sense, regardless of whether there's a for loop in R or C underneath?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Gregor, I think the confusion is between "code vectorisation" and "vectorised functions". In R, the usage seems inclined towards the latter. "Code vectorisation" describes operating on a vector of length 'k' in the same instruction. Wrapping a fn. around loopy code results in "vectorised functions" (yes, it doesn't make sense and is confusing, I agree, better would be *loop hiding* or *vector i/p functions*) and need not have anything to do with *code vectorisation*. In R, apply would be a *vectorised function*, but it doesn't vectorise your code, rather operates on vectors.

Comment: If a vectorized function is *"A plain C loop that doesn't call any R function at all and uses it own compiled functions"*, wouldn't `apply`s be conditionally vectorized since if you call a primitive function like `vapply(x, sum, numeric(1))` the function is called directly in `C` and no `R` functions are called?

Comment: @Barker No. `vapply` will still have to evaluate an R function (even if it's primitive) in each iteration.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is incorrect.  According to [the `R` release docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) *"Note that primitive functions make no use of R code, and hence are very different from the usual interpreted functions."*

Comment: @Barker The primitive function *itself* doesn't uses R code, but `vapply` still has that `FUN` argument that needs to be evaluated in each iteration. Meaning that in each iteration, C calls a C function thru R interface.

Comment: Maybe I should be posting this as a question, but could you please explain what you mean by *"calls a C function thru R interface"*?  To me that means something like `mean()` where there is an `R` defined function that calls a`.Internal()` in `C`.  I was under the impression that primitives were calling pointers to `C` functions, letting the base `C` code that makes up `R` "poke through".  Looking through the `src` for `R` I can't find anywhere that `sum` or `length` are defined in the `R` docs, only in the `C` docs.  Could you explain how and when `R` is being used by `vapply` on a primitive?

Comment: @Barker `vapply` has a `FUN` argument that being passed and stored into C. C doesn't know what that function does or if it's primitive or not. For C this is just some black box that needs to be evaluated in each iteration. It first protects it using `SEXP R_fcall = PROTECT(LCONS(FUN, LCONS(tmp, LCONS(R_DotsSymbol, R_NilValue))));` and then evaluates it in each iteration using `tmp = eval(R_fcall, rho);`- this is pritty much what I've showed in the answer.

Comment: @Barker I think your misconception is coming from an assumption that `*apply` family functions, after receiving the R function trying first to understand what it does, if the R function is is just a primitive, then they will use it's C source code instead of the R function. While in reality the `*apply` functions are much "dumber". They don't care what type of the function you are passing to them (because there are so many possibilities), rather they just store it as some black box and evaluate it in each iteration.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your response.  I just emailed one of the authors of [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/) who had to rewrite a lot of base R.  He said he would have to go back and check but he is pretty sure that "the function call `vapply(x, sum, numeric(1))` be an R function calling a C loop calling a pointer to a C function never touching R after the first function call".