# Quickly Divide specific values R

Tags: r

I have two vectors of equal length and I would like to halve the values in the first one based on a criteria from the second. As a concrete example, let

```
V1 = 1:6 ; V2 = c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
```

I would like to divide every value in V1 by 2 which corresponds to a 1 in V2.

I know how to do this using a for loop but each vector has several hundred thousand elements so it seems like there should be a much faster method.

What I am really looking for is something like the apply function but only applied to selective elements.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. mapply was exactly what I was looking for :-) . To answer your question David, the desired output would for the example would be (1, 2, 1.5, 2, 5, 3). For the specific project I only needed to divide by two but it is definitely great to know how to apply the concept to a general setting. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 5):

```
v1 = c(1:6)
v2 = c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
v1 / (v2+1)
```

More generally if you want an apply function, look at `?mapply`

```
mapply(function(x1, x2) { if (x2==1) { x1/2; } else { x1 } } , v1, v2)
```

Here's a way to do it with data.table, which is likely to be fast...

```
library(data.table)
DT[v2==1,divisor:=2]
DT[v2==0,divisor:=1]
DT[,answer:=v1/divisor]
```

Comment: Why do you recommend `mapply`? `ifelse` would be preferable.

Comment: @Roland What makes you think there is anything wrong with `mapply`?  This should be optimized under the hood, and it is not a raw loop.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28983292/1412059) might be of interest to you. `mapply` can't be as efficient as a "vectorized function".

Comment: @Roland I just suggested `mapply` because the OP asked for an apply-like function... but you're probably right that it's less efficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
v1 <- c(1:6)
v2 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1)

v1 / (v2 + 1)
#[1] 1.0 2.0 1.5 2.0 5.0 3.0
```

For using the strategy to apply a function to selected elements, you need to transform `v2` to a logical vector and use it for subsetting:

```
as.logical(v2)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
res <- v1
res[as.logical(v2)] <- res[as.logical(v2)] / 2
res
#[1] 1.0 2.0 1.5 2.0 5.0 3.0

res[as.logical(v2)]
#[1] 1.5 2.0 3.0
```

Comment: Nice answer, but will this work if, for example, you wanted to divide by 3?  (I upvoted you by the way)

Comment: I'm not sure about the desired output here. My guess is that the OP wants `v1[which(v2 == 1)]/2`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `v1 / (3 ^ v2)`