# For loop taking forever - possible to apply?

Tags: r, performance

I have a very large `data.frame`. What I am trying to do is subtract the row mean of columns 37-2574 from those columns, then divide by the row standard deviation. I then need to multiply columns 1-18 by the (same row) standard deviation. Finally, I need to subtract the row mean from columns 18-2574 from columns 19-36. I'm currently trying to do this via a `for` loop, but it is taking forever. Is there a way to do this with `apply`, or even a faster `for` loop? Here's what I have currently:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(samples)){
  theta.mean <- mean(samples[i, 37:2574])
  theta.sd <- sd(samples[i, 37:2574])
  samples[i, 37:2574] <- (samples[i, 37:2574] - theta.mean)/ theta.sd
  # then multiply columns 1-18 by SD of theta at each iteration 
  samples[i, 1:18] <- samples[i, 1:18] * theta.sd
  # subtract theta-mean * column 1-18 from columns 19-36
  for (j in 1:18){
    theta.mean.beta <- theta.mean * samples[i, j]
    samples[i, j + 18] <- samples[i, j + 18] - theta.mean.beta
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it shouldnt supposed to be  samples[i, 37:2574] <- (samples[i, 37:2574] - theta.mean[i])/ theta.sd[i] ?

Comment: and similarly   samples[i, 1:18] <- samples[i, 1:18] * theta.sd[i] 
? It would make more sense if I understand you correctly

Comment: @ECII - since I'm not storing theta.mean or theta.sd, I just write over them at each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use `apply()` to calculate all the row statistics all at once and then to do the operations column-wise like like so:

```
# calculate the row means and sds's using apply()
theta.means  <-  apply(samples[,37:2574],  # the object to summarized
                       1,                  # summarize over the rows (MARGIN = 1)
                       mean)               # the summary function 
theta.sds  <-  apply(samples[,37:2574],1,sd)

# define a function to apply for each row
standardize  <-  function(x)
    (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
# apply it it over for each row (MARGIN = 1)
samples[,37:2574]  <-  t(apply(samples[,37:2574],1,standardize))

# subtract theta-mean * column 1-18 from columns 19-36
for (j in 1:18){
    samples[, j] <- samples[,j] * theta.sds
    theta.mean.beta <- theta.means * samples[, j]
    samples[, j + 18] <- samples[, j + 18] - theta.mean.beta
}
```

Be sure and double check that this code is equivalent to your original code by taking a subset of rows (e.g. 'samples <- samples[1:100,]`) and checking that the results are the same (I would have done this my self, but there wasn't an example dataset posted...).

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a more efficient implementation based on David Arenburg's comments below:

```
# calculate the row means via rowMeans()
theta.means  <-  rowMeans(as.matrix(samples[,37:2574]))

# redefine SD to be vectorized with respect to rows in the data.frame 
rowSD <- function(x)  
    sqrt(rowSums((x - rowMeans(x))^2)/(dim(x)[2] - 1)) 

# calculate the row means and sds's using the vectorized version of SD
theta.sds  <-  rowSD(as.matrix(samples[,37:2574]))
```

Now use the fact when you subtract a vector (`x`) from a data.frame (`df`), 
R recycles the values of `x` -- and when `lengh(x) == nrow(df)` the result 
is the same as subtracting `x` from each column of `df`:

```
 # standardize columns 37 through 2574
 samples[,37:2574] <-  (samples[,37:2574] - theta.means)/theta.sds
```

Now do similar calculations for rows `1:18` and `19:36`

```
# subtract theta-mean * column 1-18 from columns 19-36
samples[, 1:18] <- samples[,1:18] * theta.sds
samples[, 1:18 + 18] <- samples[, 1:18 + 18] - theta.means * samples[,1:18] * theta.sds
```

Comment: Nice! Does the use of `apply` here over more manually-written loopy code actually speed things up with a side-by-side comparison? I'm afraid I lack a copy of R (haven't used it since my university), but knowing that a 1-to-1 translation of a for loop into `apply` actually offers a speed boost would be very useful info.

Comment: Thanks, that was great. @Ike - yes, this code is much faster than the original. The original loop never actually finished (ran for over 1 hour), and this code finished in <1 minute.

Comment: @Alex Ah yes, this code is faster but it's also smarter algorithmically. I'm mainly curious about those one-to-one side comparisons, as I may have a very incorrect notion of `apply` (I always thought of it as a shorthand rather than an optimization).

Comment: It should be faster.  If you think about `df[i,j] <- 1`, R actually replaces the entire vector `df[,j]` (or equivalently `df[[j]]`) during each iteration of the for loop, not just it's i'th element.  Using `apply()` makes just one replacement of that vector.  For more on performance in R, see Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html)

Comment: Very nice, and apologies, this info makes my previous answer completely wrong (I really thought 'apply' was a shorthand at best). I removed it in favor of your obviously superior one.

Comment: Why are you calculating row means with `apply`? There is a bult in function for that called `rowMeans`. Row wise SD can be easily vectorized too. `(x - mean(x))/sd(x)` can also be vectorizd. My guess is that the data isn't really big, otherwise this whole `apply` with margin of 1 ans-amble  would never end.

Comment: Also what's `samples[,37:2574]  <-  t(apply(samples[,37:2574],1,standardize))` for? Isn't it just `(samples[,37:2574] - theta.means)/theta.sds`?

Comment: Re: useing `apply` over `rowMeans` the only answer I've got (which is not a great answer) is habit.    `(x - mean(x))/sd(x)` is vectorized, but I'm curious how you would apply it row wise without using the apply family.

Comment: `(x - mean(x))/sd(x)` isn't vectorized when used within `apply` with a margin of one. You know `apply` is just a `for` loop right? Here's an interesting read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized. I also don't understand why you couldn't just do `(samples[,37:2574] - theta.means)/theta.sds`? Isn't it the same? What's `apply` and `t` for?

Comment: Re vectorizing `sd` over rows, use this `RowSD <- function(x) {
  sqrt(rowSums((x - rowMeans(x))^2)/(dim(x)[2] - 1))
}` and then simply `RowSD(as.matrix(samples[,37:2574]))`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, and I would absolutely do something like that it apply(df,1,sd) took longer than a few minutes to run, but the OP was asking about `apply` specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your post on apply...I agree that apply is just a for loop, but it doesn't do the element-wise asignment within a for loop, but rather there is just one assignment to the data.frame object. I assumed that was the reason that the `apply` was faster -- not that the calculations themselves were actually faster.

Comment: My moto is not to do what I told but what's right ;). `apply` with a margin of one should be avoided by all cost usually because R is vectorised language and wasn't designed to work efficiently on rows. Not to mention if you have all the vectorized functions at your disposal. Lastly, `(samples[,37:2574] - theta.means)/theta.sds` is a great lesson for the OP what vectorized means and why we don't need `for` loops (or `apply`s- which is the same). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this. This clarified for me that "vectorized" really means "vectorized with respect to existing data structure", which in this case is a data.frame (a.k.a. list) of column vectors, and it's the existing (column) vectors to which apply(df,1, foo) is not vectorized.

Comment: Vectorized basically means that it doesn't need to evaluate some function in each loop (doesn't matter if R or C). `rowMeans` is also vectorized because it calculates the means within the C code without calling `mean` from R in each loop unlike `apply` does. Though the definition of `vectorized` is somewhat arguable (it appears) as you can see by the various answers on that question.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but it sounds like `vectorized` means a few things, including avoiding unnecessary function calls ( and their overhead ), and avoiding repeatedly allocating memory (even within the memory already allocated to R by the operating system), and probably something else, by taking advantage of R's functions that pre-allocate and/or re-use memory based on the 'shape' of the arguments.