# creating a 2-dimensional array

Tags: r

I want to create a 2 dimensional array of 100,000 by 100,000 that contains values of Cp. so i  get Cp[1,] ,Cp[2,] , Cp[3,] and so on
then find all the mean for Cp[1,] and store it as meanCp[1], mean of Cp[2,] and store as meanCp[2].
Is there a better and faster way of doing this than i have here?

```
K=0.5
x=numeric()
stdCp=numeric()
meanCp=numeric()
u0=0
Cp <- matrix(0,100000,100000)
for (j in 1:100000) {
  x=rnorm(100000,0,1)
  for (i in 1:100000) {    
    if (j==1){
     Cp[j,i]= max(0,x[i]-(u0+K))
    } else {
       Cp[j,i]= max(0,x[i]-(u0+K)+Cp[j-1,i])
    }
  }
 meanCp[j]=mean(Cp[j,])
 stdCp[j]=sd(Cp[j,])
}
meanCp
```

so for example meanCp[1] gives me a value between 0.19 and 0.20

Comment: the inner for loop can be replaced with the much faster `pmax()`, 
and the calculation of meanCp and stdCp can be accomplished with 
the much faser `rowMeans()`, as in the updated response to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017316/for-loop-taking-forever-possible-to-apply/30017970#30017970)

Comment: How much memory do you have to do a thing like this? Did you realize that allocating a 100000*100000 matrix needs about 70Gb?

Comment: yes u are right. it gives error message with 100,000 X100000.                  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(0, 10000, 1e+05) :
  Reached total allocation of 3988Mb: see help(memory.size)

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference at *colMeans* function. Some other functions in the same help html would be also useful.