# R: Looping over elements of a numeric vector without vectorization

Tags: r, loops

I have am trying to loop over a numeric vector. How do I do this? Typically in a `for` loop one begins the loop with `for(i in 1:z)`. However, I want something like `for(i in vector)`. For example, see the below:

```
x <- c(839898, 3, 9)
for (i in x) { print(i) }

# Desired output
839898
3
9
```

In this instance, I do not want to `vectorize` this as I am trying to learn how to accomplish this with a `for` loop.

While this post is similar to many others, in almost all of the others I have seen only **vectorized** solutions because someone was trying to accomplish a task with minimal run time rather than learn how the loops work.

Comment: Your example works, I have no idea what else you want.

Comment: AFAIK using an `apply` function is not vectorized.  I suspect that in any solution below R will use a loop internally at some point (it will for `apply`).

Comment: It worked for me too.  Is there a reason why you don't want to work in standard R principles and vectorize things?  Loops are generally not good practice in R.

Comment: It was a typo. @Amstell, I was trying to learn and not use it for a substantive application. I also consider `apply` vectorized for this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized  Also, whoever went through my old posts and down voted is fairly pathetic - but alas, such is the internet (and the battle over reputation on an online forum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are making a typo above, and you want to print i instead of print x. Here is the execution in RStudio.

[image: Screenshot of Code Execution in RStudio]

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    print(x[i])
}
```

You are printing `x` directly which is defined the global environment. You want to print the `i`th element of `x` in the `for` loop