# How to optimize run times using multiple calls to the `apply` functions?

Tags: r, optimization, apply, primitive-types

A while ago I read two posts talking about the `apply` family of functions in `R` and if [they are "really" vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized) and whether [they improve execution time and/or memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Both posts center around the idea that "under the hood" `apply` functions are loops, with the difference being that a `for` loop goes through the loop in `R` where as the `apply`s loop in `C`.  This brings to particular interest `vapply`ing primitive functions like `sum` which [*"make no use of R code"*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) meaning

```
vapply(x, sum, numeric(1))
```

should show a particular advantage since it is executed entirely in `C`.  Sure enough, there is a pretty big speed up seen calling `sum()` directly in an `apply` versus calling it in a `R` wrapper.  (Note: all `expr` outputs from `microbenchmark` are removed for readability)

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> set.seed(100)
> mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(5000000), ncol = 10000))
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, sum, numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  10.79918 11.16559 12.33968 11.45679 11.67717 34.89015   100
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, function(x) sum(x), numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 13.92961 14.20497 15.62257 14.33341 14.64748 32.71982   100
```

This got me wondering, when is it better to call an `apply` function multiple times with primitive functions vs when is it better to call it once with an `R` wrapper.  For instance to compute means:

```
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, mean, numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 88.90804 96.81667 112.2362 108.323 117.7397 585.6286   100
> microbenchmark(colMeans(mydata))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 53.13873 57.16753 64.98141 59.10488 73.67025 100.2248   100
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, sum, numeric(1))/vapply(mydata, length, numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 15.1812 15.74453 17.59638 16.08719 16.97016 34.12331   100
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, function(x) sum(x)/length(x), numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 16.09877 17.24127 20.73641 18.23274 20.59589 58.83919   100
```

I assume the longer run time for `mean()` and `colMeans()` has to do with argument checking rather than it not being a primitive (correct me if I am wrong) (@Roland corrected me, for `colMeans()` it is because it must convert the `data.frame` to a `matrix`).  The speed up for calling the primitives `sum()` and `length()` independently rather than as `function(x) sum(x)/length(x)` was more interesting.  The difference isn't big, but it is consistently there across the `microbenchmark` distribution.  This made me wonder about calling anonymous functions where you mix primitives and non-primitive functions, so I ran:

```
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, function(x) sum(x)/sd(x), numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 161.7666 207.5839 220.5956 213.863 231.5117 623.3246   100
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, sum, numeric(1))/vapply(mydata, sd, numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 164.1759 195.0166 212.6117 207.3877 219.0822 640.5814   100
```

Once again, not a huge difference, but an improvement is there in all but the min and max of the distribution.  Finally, I decided to do one last experiment where I called two non-primitives:

```
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, function(x) mean(x)/sd(x), numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq    mean  median       uq      max neval
 290.6148 337.9683 358.855 356.099 368.3152 840.7395   100
> microbenchmark(vapply(mydata, mean, numeric(1))/vapply(mydata, sd, numeric(1)))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 246.9073 287.1489 303.7743 300.0357 319.8356 400.5652   100
```

This one really surprised me since both functions are `R` functions, so it seems like it would be better to loop once calling `R` functions than to loop twice calling `R` functions.

So for my questions:

1. Why am I getting faster run times from calling `vapply()` twice on simpler functions than once on a slightly more complex one?
2. In each of these cases, where is the speed up coming from; avoiding `R` functions by calling `apply`s directly on primitives or splitting up the function into multiple `apply`s?
3. Should I always split up my function calls into multiple simpler `apply`s rather than one complex one (even if it means 7 calls to an `apply` function) and what makes a function "simple" enough to be worth it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure David doesn't consider a vapply loop vectorized. vapply's better speed results from the known information of the results data structure. colMeans is slower because it calls as.matrix.data.frame in the beginning.

Comment: @Roland You are correct that in his answer David said he didn't feel `vapply()` is vectorized, but when it is called on a primitive, as far as I can tell it fits his definition.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I don't consider `vapply` vectorized. I don't think you understood my answer at all.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I removed the reference to your answer since you felt it was inappropriate and it was more of a motivation for the question than anything else.  I did not mean to offend.  Hopefully you will continue to engage with me on the answer I had previously linked because I understand why you don't feel `vapply(x, mean, numeric(1))` is vectorized but I don't understand why `vapply(x, sum, numeric(1))` isn't based on my understanding of how `R` calls its compiled code.

Comment: Look into overhead from S3 method dispatch to understand why `mean` is slower. Then, `.Primitive` functions are slightly more efficient than closures, but the difference is smaller than between generics and non-generics. You could also look into byte-compiling. Also, don't confuse `vapply` and `apply`. And finally, vectorized code is *at least* as fast as an R loop; usually much faster because you avoid overhead from repeated R function calls.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I think you helped me understand pretty well why the `mean()` call is slower.  Did you address why two `vapply()`s (both `C` loops) are faster than one `vapply()` that calls the same functions with an anonymous function?  I didn't see anything in your answer, but I may just not have understood it.

Comment: length(mydata) calls to / vs one call to / could be part of the reason. Benchmark /.

Comment: @Roland good point, not quite sure the right way to do that though.  I tried `var2 <- mydata[1, ]` and `system.time(vapply(var2 , "/", numeric(1), 1))` which gave me `user: 0.51, system: 0.95, elapsed: 0.51` which is more than the difference when calling the primitives and less than the difference for the other two, so I am not sure if that means I set up the experiment wrong or that we can reject that hypothesis.

Comment: Use a package like microbenchmark for proper benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks @Roland I changed the benchmarks in my question and reduced the sample data size to keep the benchmark run times reasonable.  When I did `microbenchmark` on the old data set, I got similar times as in my previous comment.  With the new data set it is `mean: 4.237, median: 4.188`.