# How can this slow R code be rewritten to be more efficient?

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, apply

Hi everybody I am trying to optimize below R code with for loops because it takes so much time to execute. I even tried compiler in R to turn the function to bytecode but performance even worse. So, Is there any way to write this code with apply functions

```
word_separation<-function(inp_data){
df<-NULL
for(k in 1:nrow(inp_data)){
    vec<-unlist(strsplit(as.vector(inp_data[k,]),split=","))
        if(length(vec)==1){
            df<-rbind(df,data.frame(first_col=vec,second_col=vec))
        }else{
            temp_df<-NULL
            for(i in 2:length(vec)){
                for(j in i:length(vec){
                    temp_df<-rbind(temp_df,data.frame(first_col=vec[1],second_col=paste(vec[i:j],collapse=",")))
                }
                df<-rbind(df,temp_df)
                df[df==""]<-NA
                df<-df %>% unique() %>% na.omit()
            }
        }
    }
    return(df)
}
```

Here my inp_data dataframe has single column with data

```
    column
Milk,Bread,Eggs,Jam
Apple,Milk,Beer
```

When passed to function returns an dataframe with columns, first column with first word and second column with combinations of other words in dataframe.

```
 first_col     second_col
   Milk          Bread
   Milk     Bread,Eggs
   Milk Bread,Eggs,Jam
   Milk           Eggs
   Milk       Eggs,Jam
   Milk            Jam
   Apple           Milk
   Apple      Milk,Beer
   Apple           Beer
```

Comment: How about a description what the method should do?

Comment: You are doing just about everything possible to make this run slowly. Always pre-allocate storage for the loop (set `df` to some size and fill it in, increase `df`'s size only if you get close to filling it if you don't know how big to make `df` at the start.); use a matrix or a list not a data frame; *never* grow objects at each iteration in a loop - you fill objects in but never grow them (except if you've filled them up and haven't finished iterating); do as few operations/function calls as possible inside a loop - move operations to higher levels or outside the loop to avoid too many calls

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please elaborate or give some examples to alert the code

Comment: also, you can have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28983292/4137985) to know more about `-apply` functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP has specified that the input data consists of a single column. So we need to split the column before creating the combinations. ([The answer given by Sathish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42770990/3817004) has silently skipped this step.)

The `data.table` solution below uses only one `lapply()`.

#### Data

**Edit:** Added row with only one word

```
library(data.table)
inp_data <- fread("    column
Milk,Bread,Eggs,Jam
Apple,Milk,Beer
Butter", sep = "\n")
```

#### Code

```
# split strings, output in long format, add row number for later join
molten <- inp_data[, rn := .I][, strsplit(column, ","), by = rn]
# create combinations of all words (except the first one)
combined <- molten[, unlist(
  lapply(seq_len(.N - 1), function(.i) as.data.table(
    combn(V1[-1], .i, paste, collapse = ",", simplify = TRUE)))), by = rn]
# right join
combined[molten[, .(rn, first_col = first(V1)), by = rn], 
         .(rn, first_col, second_col = V1), on = "rn"]
#    rn first_col     second_col
# 1:  1      Milk          Bread
# 2:  1      Milk           Eggs
# 3:  1      Milk            Jam
# 4:  1      Milk     Bread,Eggs
# 5:  1      Milk      Bread,Jam
# 6:  1      Milk       Eggs,Jam
# 7:  1      Milk Bread,Eggs,Jam
# 8:  2     Apple           Milk
# 9:  2     Apple           Beer
#10:  2     Apple      Milk,Beer
#11:  3    Butter             NA
```

**Edit:** Changed join to ensure that rows consisting of only one word are included as well.