# List of string to list of vectors of characters

Tags: r

After defining

```
> Seq.genes <- as.list(c("ATGCCCAAATTTGATTT","AGAGTTCCCACCAACG"))
```

I have a list of strings :

```
> Seq.genes[1:2]
[[1]]
[1] "ATGCCCAAATTTGATTT"

[[2]]
[1] "AGAGTTCCCACCAACG"
```

I would like to convert it in a list of vectors :

```
>Seq.genes[1:2]
[[1]]
[1]"A" "T" "G" "C" "C" "C" "A" "A" "A" "T" "T" "T" "G" "A" "T" "T" "T"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "G" "A" "G" "T" "T" "C" "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "A" "A" "C" "G"
```

I tried something like :

```
for (i in length(Seq.genes)){
  x <- Seq.genes[i]
  Seq.genes[i] <- substring(x, seq(1,nchar(x),2), seq(1,nchar(x),2))

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be better to have the strings in a `vector` rather than in a `list`.  So, we could `unlist`, then do an `strsplit`

```
strsplit(unlist(Seq.genes), "")
```

Comment: Do note that the `strsplit` itself returns a list object, with an entry for each element in the input vector (`unlist(Seq.genes)`). The code you provided will give the exact output as OP requested.

Comment: @MrGumble  Yes, it returns a list object.  In this case it may be better to have a list

Answer (score -1):

```
sapply(Seq.genes, strsplit, split = '')
```

or

```
lapply(Seq.genes, strsplit, split = '')
```

Comment: Why sapply loop?

Comment: it is not a loop. sapply() and lapply() just apply a function to a list.

Comment: @dapeng Not quite. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized)