# Export R plot to multiple formats

Tags: r, plot, graphics

Since it is possible to export R plots to PDF *or* PNG *or* SVG etc., is it also possible to export an R plot to multiple formats *at once*?  E.g., export a plot to PDF *and* PNG *and* SVG without recalculating the plot?

Comment: Not with base graphics, with package `ggplot2` yes.

Comment: I'd say not even with ggplot2. The ggplot2 and other grid solutions create a plotting program that is then passed to a print engine before being sent to a device. They will need to be "recalculated" every time they are `print`-ed.

Comment: Excuse me, do you find anyone's answer useful?

Comment: @ytu IINM the current answers seem to recalculate the plot for each output device?  If that is the case then user 42 gave the correct answer, but in a comment.

Comment: I'd say not really. If you're using `dev.copy`, according to its document, it "*copies the graphics contents of the current device to the device specified*", i.e. the plot is not recalculated, but copied. On the other hand, `sapply` is a function doing iteration at C level (you can find related discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized)). You may call it "recalculating", but it is typically much faster than a `for` loop for the same job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using `ggplot2` and other packages, here are two alternative solutions.

1. Create a function generating a plot with specified device and `sapply` it

   ```
   # Create pseudo-data
   x <- 1:10
   y <- x + rnorm(10)

   # Create the function plotting with specified device
   plot_in_dev <- function(device) {
     do.call(
       device,
       args = list(paste("plot", device, sep = "."))  # You may change your filename
     )
     plot(x, y)  # Your plotting code here
     dev.off()
   }

   wanted_devices <- c("png", "pdf", "svg")
   sapply(wanted_devices, plot_in_dev)
   ```
2. Use the built-in function `dev.copy`

   ```
   # With the same pseudo-data
   # Plot on the screen first
   plot(x, y)

   # Loop over all devices and copy the plot there
   for (device in wanted_devices) {
     dev.copy(
       eval(parse(text = device)),
       paste("plot", device, sep = ".")  # You may change your filename
     )
     dev.off()
   }
   ```

The second method may be a little tricky because it requires [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). Yet it works as well. Both methods work on other plotting systems including `ggplot2` simply by substituting the plot-generating codes for the `plot(x, y)` above - you probably need to `print` the ggplot object explicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely!  Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
data("cars")
p <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()

prefix <- file.path(getwd(),'test.')

devices <- c('eps', 'ps', 'pdf', 'jpeg', 'tiff', 'png', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wmf')

walk(devices,
     ~ ggsave(filename = file.path(paste(prefix, .x)), device = .x))
```