# Confused by a vapply function using grepl internally (Part of datacamp course)

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, grepl

```
hits <- vapply(titles,
           FUN = grepl,
           FUN.VALUE = logical(length(pass_names)),
           pass_names)
```

`titles` is a vector with titles such as `"mr"`, `pass_names` is a list of names.

2 questions.

1. I don't understand the resulting matrix hits
2. I don't understand why the last line is `pass_names` nor what how I am supposed to know about these 4 arguments. Under `?vapply` it specificies the x, `FUN`, `FUN.VALUE` but I cannot figure out how I am supposed to figure out that `pass_names` needs to be listed there.

I have looked online and could not find an answer, so I hope this will help others too. Thank you in advance for your answers, yes I am a beginner.

---

Extra info: This question uses the titanic package in R, `pass_names` is just `titanic$Name`, `titles` is just `paste(",", c("Mr\\.", "Master", "Don", "Rev", "Dr\\.", "Major", "Sir", "Col", "Capt", "Jonkheer"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be a bit confused.

The `vapply` code chunk in your question is equivalent to:

```
hits <- vapply(titles,
               FUN = function(x) grepl(x, pass_names),
               FUN.VALUE = logical(length(pass_names)))
```

`vapply` takes a `...` argument which takes as many arguments as are provided. If the arguments are not named (see @Roland's comment), the n-th argument in the `...` position is passed to the n+1-th argument of `FUN` (the first argument to `FUN` is `X`, *i.e.* `titles` in this case).

The resulting matrix has the same number of rows as the number of rows in `titanic` and has 10 columns, the length of `titles`. The `[i, j]`-th entry is `TRUE` if the `i`-th `pass_names` matches the `j`-th regular expression in `titles`, `FALSE` if it doesn't.

Comment: `*apply` functions can do name matching for arguments in `...`. Therefore `X` must not be the first argument; e.g., `lapply(1:4, matrix, data = 1)` works.

Comment: From solving this question it is very evident to me that I just do not understand how these functions work at all. Let me try to see if I get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are passing two vectors in your `vapply` which is equivalent to two nested `for` loops. Each pairing is then passed into the required arguments of grepl: `grepl(pattern, x)`.

Specifically, on first loop of `vapply` the first item in *titles* is compared with every item of *pass_names*. Then on second loop, the second item in *titles* is compared again to all items of *pass_names* and so on until first vector, *titles*, is exhausted.

To illustrate, you can equivalently build a *hits2* matrix using nested `for` loops, rendering exactly as your vapply output, *hits*:

```
hits2 <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(df$name), ncol=length(titles))
colnames(hits2) <- titles

for (i in seq_along(df$name)) {

  for (j in seq_along(titles)) {

    hits2[i, j] <- grepl(pattern=titles[j], x=df$name[i])

  }

}

all.equal(hits, hits2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, you can run same exact in `sapply` without the required *FUN.VALUE* argument as both `sapply` and `vapply` are wrappers to `lapply`. However, `vapply` is more preferred as you proactively assert your output while `sapply` renders one way depending on function. For instance, in `vapply` you could render an integer matrix with: `FUN.VALUE = integer(length(pass_names))`.

```
hits3 <- sapply(titles, FUN = grepl, pass_names)

all.equal(hits, hits3)
# [1] TRUE
```

All in all, the *apply* family are more concise, compact ways to run iterations and renders a data structure instead of initializing and assigning a vector/matrix with `for` or `while` loops.

For further reading, consider this interesting SO post: [Is the “*apply” family really not vectorized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized)