# R: apply vs do.call

Tags: r, apply, do.call

I just read the profile of @David Arenburg, and found a bunch of useful tips for how to develop good R-programming skills/habits, and one especially struck me. I have always thought that the apply functions in R was the cornerstone of working with dataframes, but he writes:

> If you are working with data.frames, forget there is a function called
>   apply- whatever you do - don't use it. Especially with a margin of 1
>   (the only good usecase for this function is to operate over matrix
>   columns- margin of 2).
>
> Some good alternatives: ?do.call, ?pmax/pmin, ?max.col,
>   ?rowSums/rowMeans/etc, the awesome matrixStats packages (for
>   matrices), ?rowsum and many more

Could anybody explain this to me? Why are apply functions frowned upon?

Comment: I'm actually talking specifically about `apply`- not the whole `*apply` family. The main issue with `apply` is that it converts the whole data to a matrix which messes up the data (because `matrix` can't store different classes unlike a dataframe), hence yields unexpected results. Hence, when operating over columns, it is better to use the rest of the `*apply` family such as `lapply` or `sapply`. On the other hand, because R is vectorized language `apply` with a margin of 1 will be very slow (regardless of the `matrix` issue), hence I'm offering to use vectorized alternatives instead.

Comment: Aha, I see, thank you very much for clearing that up!

Comment: Also, [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized) a useful read about the `*apply` family.

Comment: Great! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `apply(DF, 1, f)` converts each row of `DF` to a vector and then passes that vector to f.  If `DF` were a mix of strings and numbers then the row would be converted to a character vector before passing it to `f` so that, for example, `apply(iris, 1, function(x) sum(x[-5]))` will not work even though the row `iris[i, -5]` contains all numeric elements.  The row is converted to character string and you can't sum character strings.  On the other hand `apply(iris[-5], 1, sum)` will work the same as `rowSums(iris[-5])`.
- if `f` produces a vector the result is a matrix and not another data frame; also, the result is the transpose of what you might expect.  This

  ```
  apply(BOD, 1, identity)
  ```

  gives the following rather than giving `BOD` back:

  ```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  Time    1.0  2.0    3    4  5.0  7.0
  demand  8.3 10.3   19   16 15.6 19.8
  ```

  Many years ago Hadley Wickham did [post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-January/086064.html) `iapply` which is idempotent in the sense that `iapply(mat, 1, identity)` returns `mat`, rather than `t(mat)`, where `mat` is a matrix.  More recently with his plyr package one can write:

  ```
  library(plyr)
  ddplyr(BOD, 1, identity)
  ```

  and get `BOD` back as a data frame.

On the other hand `apply(BOD, 1, sum)` will give the same result as `rowSums(BOD)` and `apply(BOD, 1, f)` might be useful for functions `f` for which `f` produces a scalar and there is no counterpart such as in the `sum` /  `rowSums` case.  Also if `f` produces a vector and you don't mind a matrix result you can transpose the output of `apply` yourself and although ugly it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I think what the author means, is that you should use pre-built/vectorized functions (because it is easier), if you can and avoid apply (because in principle it is a for loop and takes longer):

```
library(microbenchmark)

d <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                b = rnorm(10, 200, 1))

# bad - loop
microbenchmark(apply(d, 1, function(x) if (x[1] < x[2]) x[1] else x[2]))

# good - vectorized but same result
microbenchmark(pmin(d[[1]], d[[2]])) # use double brackets!

# edited:
# -------
# bad: lapply
microbenchmark(data.frame(lapply(d, round, 1)))

# good: do.call faster than lapply
microbenchmark(do.call("round", list(d, digits = 1)))

# --------------
# Unit: microseconds
#                                  expr     min    lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# do.call("round", list(d, digits = 1)) 104.422 107.1 148.3419 134.767 184.524 332.009   100
#                            expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
# data.frame(lapply(d, round, 1)) 235.619 243.2055 298.5042 252.353 276.004 1550.265   100
#
#                                  expr    min      lq    mean median       uq     max neval
# do.call("round", list(d, digits = 1)) 96.389 97.5055 113.075 98.175 105.5375 730.954   100
#                            expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
# data.frame(lapply(d, round, 1)) 235.619 243.2055 298.5042 252.353 276.004 1550.265   100
```

Comment: so all apply functions are essentially loops? lapply, sapply etc?

Comment: How does this answer `do.call` part?

Comment: Edited. (.. and regarding for-loop; according to https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf using apply's is loop hiding)

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `microbenchmark` to your answer?

Comment: @Erosennin - yes apply family are loops. Consider reading this [question by @DavidArunberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized).

Answer (score 1):

It is related to how R stores matrices and data frames*. As you may know, a `data.frame` is a `list` of vectors, that is, each column in the `data.frame` is a vector. Being a vectorized language, it is preferable to operate on vectors and that is the reason `apply` with margin of 2 is frowned upon: by doing so you will not be working on vectors, rather, you will be spanning across different vectors on each iteration.

As far as I know, using `apply` with margin 1 is not much different than using `do.call`. Although the latter might allow some more usage flexibility.

*This information should be somewhere in the [manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html).