# Loops in R with big data set, a better way?

Tags: r, loops

I am using R and have a big datesets containing 12,224,433 rows.
For every row I want to do a spearman correlation test against one vector
and extract P values. The scripts are like this:

```
pvals <- numeric(nrow(SNP))

for(i in 1:nrow(SNP)) {

  fit <- cor.test(vector, as.numeric(SNP[i,c(4:50)]), method='spearman', exact=FALSE)    

  pvals[i] <-  fit$p.value

  names(pvals)[i] <- paste(SNP$V1[i], SNP$V2[i])

}
```

The thing is it takes ages, I kind of calculate already, it took 2 hours to run only the first 70,000 rows. So it can take 200 hours.
Is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Can you post the first couple of rows of the data set so we have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good candidate for using parallel processing with a package such as `foreach` or `future.apply`.

The code below makes use of `future.apply` because of how simple that package is to use.

The general strategy is to take the action you want to repeat (i.e. getting p-values based on a subset of data), turn that action into a function, and use `future.apply` to repeat that function for the different subsets of data you want to use.

```r
library(future.apply)

# Establish method used for parallel processing
  plan(multiprocess)

# Convert the relevant subset of the matrix to numeric
  snp_subset <- SNP[,c(4:50)]
  class(snp_subset) <- 'numeric'

# Define a function to get p.values for a given row of the matrix
  get_pvals <- function(row_index) {
    pvals <- cor.test(vector, snp_subset[row_index,], method = 'spearman', exact = FALSE)$p.value
    names(pvals) <- paste(SNP$V1[row_index], SNP$V2[row_index])
    pvals
  }

# Use parallel processing to get p-values for each row of the matrix
  pvals <- future_sapply(X = seq_len(nrow(SNP)),
                         FUN = get_pvals)
```

Comment: that's awsome. I will also follow the advice above to put name() outside the loop

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I can suggest based on the info you have shared. I have added my thoughts as comments in the code -

```
# convert all rows to numeric matrix instead of as.numeric(SNP[i,c(4:50)]) in every loop
# also subsetting matrix directly gives you a vector which is what is needed for cor.test()
y <- as.matrix(SNP[, c(4:50)])

# initialize pvals with NA and then replace each value in every loop run
pvals <- rep(NA_real_, nrow(SNP))

for(i in 1:nrow(SNP)) {

  fit <- cor.test(vector, y[i, ], method = 'spearman', exact = FALSE)    

  pvals[i] <-  fit$p.value

}

# you can assign all names in one go instead of doing it in the loop
names(pvals) <- paste(SNP$V1, SNP$V2)
```

Finally, yours is a classic use case for parallel processing. Using parallel processing packages like `foreach` you can run multiple tests in parallel and then combine them into your result vector `pval`.

Also suggest you to read the book **'The R Inferno'** for more info on how to improve code efficiency.

Comment: you might be able to shave a little bit more by extracting only the necessary bits from `cor.test.default()` (but it would be a nuisance)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the suggestion. Feel free to add to or edit the answer. I am unfamiliar with `cor.test()` or `cor.test.default()` so can't do it myself. Thanks!

Comment: I thought I have to use some parallel processing packages. But by moving the name() out of the loop alone save already enormous time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
SNP["pvals"] <- apply(SNP[ ,c(4:50)], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) cor.test(vector, as.numeric(row), method='spearman', exact=FALSE)$p.value)

#SNP$pvals
```

Comment: Turns out `apply` behaves similar to `for` where it runs calls at the R level (not C level like other members of apply family). See this [canonical question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006276/1422451) from @DavidArenburg who answered own question.