# Convert loop to apply while building list

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply, sapply

I am trying to build a list of lists in R with an apply function rather than a loop, but I'm having trouble converting a working loop into an lapply format.  Allow me to explain the situation a bit more:

I have a function in R (`getDetails`) that retrieves details associated with parameters that I pass to the function and returns the result in a list.  The function works well if I pass it a single record, and I've also built a loop that that allows me to loop through a dataframe one row at a time, and pass the elements of the dataframe, row-by-row to my function which in turn returns a list to the i-th element of my list of lists (`detailsList[[i]]`).  I am trying to figure out how to convert my for loop into an apply function.  Can you assist me with this?  I've created a toy example, that if I can get working, will allow me to generalize this to my actual `getDetails` function.

```
#use cars dataset for an example
data(cars)
#get number of rows
numrows<-dim(cars)[1]
#initialize empty list
detailsList<-vector("list", numrows)

#This is a toy example of the loop I want to convert to an apply
#I'm having trouble because this builds up a list and returns the results
#to my detailsList one element at a time and I'm not sure how to do this 
#in an apply.
for (i in 1:numrows){
  detailsList[[i]]<-getDetails(cars[i,])
}

detailsList

getDetails<-function(parameters){
   valueA<-parameters[1]+45
   valueB<-parameters[1]+10
   list(valueA, valueB)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I thought I just figured this out, but it seems when I do this, I get an third dimension in my list so when I use this:

```
allDetails <- lapply(1:numrows, function(i)  getDetails(cars[i,]))
```

the second element of the first list can only be accessed with `allDetails[[1]][[1]][2]` instead of with `allDetails[[1]][2]` as I was hoping.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Note: [*apply* functions are loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28983292/1422451) (just hidden ones).

Comment: Thanks, @parfait.  I understand that that the apply functions are the same as loops, but this is precesily why I'm trying to convert my loop into an apply -- the issue is, I'm not sure how to go about it in this example since I'm building a list inside of my loop and I've never really done this with an apply function before despite my having used apply functions without any difficulty in the past (because I wasn't building a list of lists inside the looping).  I updated my response with what I thought was right at first, but it seems it's adding a third dimensions to the list of lists.

Comment: Third element? Your function returns two elements in a list. Try replacing `list()` with `c()` assuming the value objects are single-item vectors.

Comment: Ah yes.  Sorry.  I meant second.  That's what I get for working with a toy example and applying it to my actual work (which does have a third element).  I've updated the update.  I'll try using c() as opposed to list.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Parfait, you are the man (or woman)!  Thank so much for your help.  using just c() as opposed to list() at the end of my function did the trick.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just figured this out after a little help from @Parfait (thank, @Parfait!).  In case anyone else was looking for an answer, this worked for me, but I'd welcome any other answers:

```
lapply(1:numrows, function(i)  getDetails(cars[i,]))
```

and I had to modify my function to return a vector instead of a list:

```
getDetails<-function(parameters){
   valueA<-parameters[1]+45
   valueB<-parameters[1]+10
   c(valueA, valueB)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your loop written with `vapply`

```
out <- vapply(1:nrow(cars), 
              function (i) {
                valA <- .subset2(cars, 1)[i] + 45L
                valB <- .subset2(cars, 1)[i] + 10L
                c(valA, valB)
              }, numeric(2))
t(out) 
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   49   14
# [2,]   49   14
# [3,]   52   17
# [4,]   52   17
# [5,]   53   18
# [6,]   54   19
# [7,]   55   20
# ...
# (returns an array instead of a list, but that can be changed easily).
```

Btw, I don't know what your end goal is, but as far as this example goes, why *any* loop at all?

```
# vectorized
cbind(.subset2(cars, 1) + 45L, .subset2(cars, 1) + 10L)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   49   14
# [2,]   49   14
# [3,]   52   17
# [4,]   52   17
# [5,]   53   18
# [6,]   54   19
# [7,]   55   20
# ...
# or similar result with
# getDetails(cars) (version with c())
```

Comment: Thanks @nate. the "looping" has to happen because I have to look up the details in an external 3d-party application one at a time.  This was just a toy example to help me figure out to to implement in my much more complex program.  Thanks for your help!