# Use sapply or Vector?

Tags: r, sapply

I'm new to R and I find it ambiguous whether I should use a vector as the argument to call a function or use sapply instead to give the variables in the vector to the function one by one.

Isn't it the same thing? Why sapply exists if it's the same thing? Is there times when I should use one way or the other and how to know which way to use?

This question came to my mind because I was writing this

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) dnorm(i,0,1))
```

Then I accidentally discovered that I could do

```
dnorm(1:3,0,1)
```

How could I know it if I didn't discover it by accident (in order not to do the same mistake with other functions )?

Discovering that I tried to change in the same way this code

```
kappa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

sapply(kappa, function(t) 
  optimize(function(x) (t*x^22+5*x+6), c(-10,10))$minimum)
```

to this

```
kappa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

  optimize(function(x) (kappa*x^22+5*x+6), c(-10,10))$minimum
```

but it didn't work!

Please I need a good explanation.

Thank you

Comment: take a look at the function documentation. the first argument of `dnorm` is a vector, hence it is pointless to use `sapply`. on the other hand, the function `optimize` does not accept vector as argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, `sapply`, and similarly its siblings of the *apply* family, are loops to build a vector/matrix, or list from a multiple-item object. See this canonical answer on subject: [Is the "*apply" family really not vectorized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized). However, some operations are vectorized (i.e., loops are run at machine level such as in C or Fortran) and can receive a vector or list and operate in very quick runtime.

Almost always, the non-looped version will run faster. Below shows timings for a much larger sequence input.

```
system.time({sapply(1:300000, function(i) dnorm(i,0,1))})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.097   0.026   1.169

system.time({dnorm(1:300000,0,1)})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.006   0.001   0.007
```

As you found out `dnorm` is such a vectorized function. Many R functions can accept vectors or lists to return equal length outputs including `paste`, `lengths`, `toupper`, `[`, `file.*` family, `as.*` family, `grep` family. However, more complex, multi-layered operations require iterative calls to return single objects as you found out with `optim`. Other non-vectorized methods include `read.csv`, `write.csv`, `merge`, `lm`, `glm`, and `summary`. With these such methods, the *apply* family can then iteratively call them and bind all elements into a singular object such as vector/matrix or list.

```
kappa <- seq(1,7)

sapply(kappa, function(i) optimize(function(x) (i^x^2+5*x+6), c(-10,10))$minimum)
# [1] -9.9999263 -1.2407389 -0.9122106 -0.7784485 -0.7022782 -0.6517733 -0.6151620
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you have a vector, you should always use `dnorm(1:3,0,1)`-like syntax instead of `sapply`. It is simply faster and more elegant. The only exception is when the function you use is not vectorised (it is stated in the help page that the argument should be a single character/number or this is your own function which you know is not vectorised).

`sapply` is nice for lists:

```
> sapply(list(c(1:5), 5), sum)
[1] 15  5
> sum(list(c(1:5), 5))
Error in sum(list(c(1:5), 5)) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

And `apply` for matrices:

```
> apply(matrix(1:4, 2, 2), 1, sum)
[1] 4 6
> apply(matrix(1:4, 2, 2), 2, sum)
[1] 3 7
> sum(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
[1] 10
```

And as @davide said in the comment, `optimize` does not take vector as input.