# How to identify row that matches vector

Tags: r, tibble

I want to identify which row matches the information in a vector. As an example, I'll use the `iris` dataset (in `tibble` format to better approximate my situation): `iris %>% as_tibble()`. Then I have a tibble with a single row, which came directly from the original dataset:

```
choice <– structure(list(Sepal.Length = 4.5, Sepal.Width = 2.3, Petal.Length = 1.3, 
    Petal.Width = 0.3, Species = structure(1L, .Label = c("setosa", 
    "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
1          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa
```

I want to identify which row matches this exactly. I think it's better if it's a vector, but that's going to depend on what the function is; if that's the case, than you just have to add an `as.numeric()` to that `choice`.

The correct row is 42.

Comment: Related: [Which lines of a matrix are equal to a certain vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632037/which-lines-of-a-matrix-are-equal-to-a-certain-vector/54632523#54632523)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is `Map`.  With `Map`, we compare (`==`) the corresponding elements (here the unit is a column) of 'iris' and 'choice' (as choice have only a single row, that element is recycled), returning a `list` of `logical` vectors which is then `Reduce`d to a single logical `vector` with `&` i.e. it checks for the elementwise corresponding elements of the `list` (columns of iris converted to logical), returns TRUE if all the elements are TRUE), then wrap with `which` to get the position index of that logical vector

```
which(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, iris, choice)))
#[1] 42
```

---

Or another option is to replicate the rows of 'choice' to make the dim same as 'iris', do a `==`, use `rowSums` and check if it is equal to number of columns

```
library(tidyr)
which(rowSums(iris == uncount(choice, nrow(iris))) == ncol(iris))
#[1] 42
```

---

Or this can be done in `tidyverse`.  Create a row number column (`row_number()`), use `filter` with `if_all` to loop across the column names except the 'rn', compare with the extracted corresponding column of 'choice', so that it returns the row only when all the columns for that row are TRUE (`if_all`, `if_any` - is either one of them), `pull` the column 'rn' as a vector

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%  
    filter(if_all(all_of(names(choice)), 
            ~ . == choice[[cur_column()]])) %>%
     pull(rn)
#[1] 42
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! But what does `Reduce` do? (Just out of curiosity...)

Comment: BTW, I just haven't accepted yet because StackOverflow is complaining it's too soon.

Comment: @ÉricoPatto `Map` does the columnwise  comparison for each dataset and returns a `list`.  (as choice have only one row, that element is recycled).  Then `Reduce`, checks if all the corresponding elements of the `list` are TRUE (with `&`)

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it now... Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to akrun's first solution, I offer the tidyverse version of it:

```
map2(iris, choice, `==`) %>% 
  reduce(`&`) %>%
  which()

[1] 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
> which(do.call(paste, iris) == do.call(paste, choice))
[1] 42
```

or

```
> match(data.frame(t(choice)), data.frame(t(iris)))
[1] 42
```