# Remove nested for loop with if condition in R

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization, nested-loops, rbind

I am trying to optimize my R code by removing nested for loop with vectorization. My nested for loop include rbind based on if condition. Nested for loop code works however, when running vectorized code using rbind, doesn't fill the new dataframe.

For the background, I have two dataframes-'ip' , 'ip_error'. Data frame ‘ip’ with Dimension is ‘469    5’. Data frame ‘ip_error’ is with Dimension is ‘9   11’. After comparison of two data frames on the specific columns of task start and end with session start and end, my output is the selected rows from data frame ‘ip’.

This is my working code with nested for loop

```
for(j in 1:length(ip$RUID_KEY)){
 for(i in 1:length(ip_error$RUID_KEY)){
  if(isTRUE(ip_error$RUID_KEY[i]==ip$RUID_KEY[j]&&ip_error$TASK_START[i]>=ip$sess_start[j]&&ip_error$TASK_END[i]<ip$sess_end[j])){
    ev_ip_error<-rbind(ev_ip_error,ip[j,])
  }
}
}
```

My code with vectorization is as follows, which does not work

```
al<-1:length(ip$RUID_KEY)
bl<-1:length(ip_error$RUID_KEY)

f<- function(i,j){
  if(isTRUE(ip_error$RUID_KEY[i]==ip$RUID_KEY[j]&&ip_error$TASK_START[i]>=ip$sess_start[j]&&ip_error$TASK_END[i]<ip$sess_end[j])){
    ev_ip_error<-rbind(ev_ip_error,ip[j,])
  }
}

mapply(f,al,bl)
```

Here is example of my data frames, where for rows 1 and 3 in 'ip_error' satisfy the if condition

```
No.     RUID_KEY    sess_start  sess_end
1   101 2018-12-01 22:48:18.827 2018-12-01 22:55:18.900
2   201 2018-12-01 13:10:20.100 2018-12-01 13:50:10.000
3   201 2018-12-12 11:10:10.100 2018-12-12 11:20:00.100
```

‘ip_error’ data frame

```
No. RUID_KEY    TASK_START  TASK_END    TASK_NAME
1   101 2018-12-01 22:50:18.827 2018-12-01 22:50:18.827 ERROR1
2   101 2018-12-01 15:10:20.100 2018-12-01 15:10:20.100 ERROR2
3   201 2018-12-01 13:40:10.100 2018-12-01 13:40:10.100 ERROR1
```

```
ev_ip_error<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=0))
x<-c("RUID_KEY", "sess_start", "sess_end")
colnames(ev_ip_error)<-x
```

Comment: This would be a better question with some short example input data and what you want as an outcome.  In particular, are all the values of  `ip_error$RUID_KEY` unique?

Comment: ip_error$RUID_KEY is not unique. I have edited my question with example.

Comment: Code has to error out as *ev_ip_error* is never defined. Also, `mapply` like other apply family members are hidden loops. You may be applying [code vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986505/1422451) but not [calculated vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006276/1422451).

Comment: ev_ip_error is an empty data frame, which I have defined with column names as same as 'ip' data frame

Comment: Have you tried extending `f<- function(i,j)` by `f<- function(i,j,ev_ip_error)`? Or use `ev_ip_error<<-` instead of `ev_ip_error<-`?

Comment: I have added the code for initialization of my 'ev_ip_error' dataframe. Actually, my nested for loop code works and rows from 'ip' data frame does get copied into my empty data frame 'ev_ip_error'. I just want to optimize this code to run on large data set.

Comment: @geoidiot both your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: There’s no need to put `isTRUE` around a single conditional. The function is only needed to coerce non-`logical` values, or values that might be a vector of length >1, but this can never be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `merge` of the two data frames and then `subset` by time:

```
ev_ip_error <- subset(merge(ip, ip_error, by="RUID_KEY", suffixes=c("", "_")),
                      TASK_START >= sess_start & TASK_END < sess_end)[names(ip)]

ev_ip_error

#   No. RUID_KEY          sess_start            sess_end
# 1   1      101 2018-12-01 22:48:18 2018-12-01 22:55:18
# 3   2      201 2018-12-01 13:10:20 2018-12-01 13:50:10
```

Which is equivalent to ***unadjusted*** `for` loop and ***corrected*** `mapply` (or `Map`) approach that builds a list of data frames with `expand.grid` (for all possible combinations between `RUID_KEY` values). Since apply family solutions do not save scoped variables you need to build object outside its loop or call `rbind` **once** outside loop. This would be more efficient than `for` loop. See below:

```
prms <- expand.grid(al = 1:length(ip$RUID_KEY),
                    bl = 1:length(ip_error$RUID_KEY))

f <- function(i,j){
  if(isTRUE(ip_error$RUID_KEY[i]==ip$RUID_KEY[j] && ip_error$TASK_START[i]>=ip$sess_start[j] && ip_error$TASK_END[i]<ip$sess_end[j])){
     return(ip[j,])
  }
}

df_list <- mapply(f, prms$al, prms$bl, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#df_list <- Map(f, prms$al, prms$bl)   # EQUIVALENT

ev_ip_error <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

See comparison of all three approaches in <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/SGFWZ16284)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the code with merge did work for me. But the one with mapply was filling in Null value in df_list.

Comment: Hmmm...that would mean nothing met the `if` condition and so `return` was `NULL`. However, if you see the online demo using your exact posted data, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the data.table package and using inner join with inequality conditions. It's fast and straightforward to use once you get used to the syntax.

**Here is the setup:**

Step 1: create the example dataset:

```
ip <- data.table::data.table(
  ruid_key = c(101, 201, 201),
  sess_start = as.POSIXct(c(
    '2018-12-01 22:48:18.827',
    '2018-12-01 13:10:20.100',
    '2018-12-12 11:10:10.100'
    )),
  sess_end = as.POSIXct(c(
    '2018-12-01 22:55:18.900',
    '2018-12-01 13:50:10.000',
    '2018-12-12 11:20:00.100')))


ip_error <- data.table::data.table(
  ruid_key = c(101,101,201),
  task_start = as.POSIXct(c(
    '2018-12-01 22:50:18.827',
    '2018-12-01 15:10:20.100',
    '2018-12-01 13:40:10.100'
  )),
  task_end = as.POSIXct(c(
    '2018-12-01 22:50:18.827',
    '2018-12-01 15:10:20.100',
    '2018-12-01 13:40:10.100'
  ))
)
```

Step 2. do inner join, add inequalities directly to the `on` condition in the join

```
ip[ip_error, 
   on = c('ruid_key', 'sess_start<=task_start', 'sess_end>task_end'),
   .(sess_start = x.sess_start, sess_end = x.sess_end),
   nomatch = NULL
   ]
```

Comment: Your code did work on a small sample on R studio,  but the same gave me error when run on jupyter notebook on a larger data set. The error is:   Error in `[.data.frame`(ip, ip_error, on = c("RUID_KEY", "sess_start<=TASK_START", : unused arguments (on = c("RUID_KEY", "sess_start<=TASK_START", "sess_end>TASK_END"), nomatch = NULL)
Traceback:

1. ip[ip_error, on = c("RUID_KEY", "sess_start<=TASK_START", "sess_end>TASK_END"), 
 .     .(RUID_KEY = x.RUID_KEY, EVENT_SPEC_1 = x.EVENT_SPEC_1, sess_start = x.sess_start, 
 .         sess_end = x.sess_end, sess_dur = x.sess_dur), nomatch = NULL]

Comment: You need to turn the data.frame into data.table

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works now. Also it is fast on large data set.