# Using the data.table package, which will deliver the fastest user time? (R Programming)

Tags: r

I had this question in a test in an online training. I got it right just by trial and error. Most likely, I am doing something wrong because I am a beginner in R programming.

This is the question:

[image: question image]

Before you read my R code, take note that for the last part I had to convert all the columns to numeric, because without that I was getting the following message:

> "Error in rowMeans(DT) : 'x' must be numeric."

In the test, my professor solution is: "***DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]***"

With my R code, the right answer is ***mean(DT$pwgtp15, by=DT$SEX)***.

I get this output:

[image: Output Image]

My doubt is that maybe my way to make work ***DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]*** produces a slow computation.

For that, I used

```
DT <- data.frame(data.matrix(DT))
```

***Which one is the right answer? The professor solution? My answer? Another one?***

Here is my code:

```
#THE SOLUTION IS DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]
#HOWEVER, my solution is mean(DT$pwgtp15, by=DT$SEX)

install.packages("data.table")

library("data.table")

# the example below runs 100 times
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv", destfile = "ACS.csv")

DT <- fread("ACS.csv", sep = ",")



counter<- 0
myName<-"DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]"
for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<-b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")



counter<- 0
myName<-"mean(DT[DT$SEX==1,]$pwgtp15);mean(DT[DT$SEX==2,]$pwgtp15)"
for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  mean(DT[DT$SEX==1,]$pwgtp15); mean(DT[DT$SEX==2,]$pwgtp15)
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<-b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")



counter<- 0
myName<-"sapply(split(DT$pwgtp15,DT$SEX),mean)"
for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  sapply(split(DT$pwgtp15,DT$SEX),mean)
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<-b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")



counter<- 0
myName<-"tapply(DT$pwgtp15, DT$SEX, mean)"
for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  tapply(DT$pwgtp15, DT$SEX, mean)
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<-b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")



counter<- 0
myName<-"mean(DT$pwgtp15, by=DT$SEX)"
for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  mean(DT$pwgtp15, by=DT$SEX)
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<- b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")



#We convert the entire DATAFRAME to numeric
#Otherwise rowmeans will not work
DT <- data.frame(data.matrix(DT))


counter<- 0
myName<-"rowMeans(DT)[DT$SEX==1];rowMeans(DT)[DT$SEX==2]"

for (i in 1:100)
{
  a<- Sys.time()  
  rowMeans(DT)[DT$SEX==1];rowMeans(DT)[DT$SEX==2]
  b<-Sys.time()
  myTime<- b-a
  counter<- counter + myTime
}
cat("counter is: ", counter, "myName is: ", myName, "\n")
```

Comment: Hmmmm...I cannot get `mean(..., by=...)` to work beyond showing a single `mean` value. *by* argument is entirely ignored. Docs do not show either. Please show `packageVersion("data.table")`.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for your help! Did you use? DT <- fread("ACS.csv", sep = ",")

Comment: @Parfait When  I use packageVersion("data.table"), I get ‘1.12.8’

Comment: Yes and the return of `mean(DT$pwgtp15, by=DT$SEX)` is one single value not like others split by `SEX`.

Comment: @Parfait When you use it outside of a loop you get a single mean value. As I am measuring the time that R uses for the calculation,  the code registers the time after and before. The difference is the time for one calculation. The process is done 100 times, and those times are added.

Comment: @ Sorry. I just understood  your comment. You are right. Just one value appears. Maybe that is why it is the fastest.

Comment: Never mind the times. All the methods you are testing should return the same output by themselves. `mean()` does not. The *by* argument is ignored. This is exactly why it is so much faster because it does not split and calculate. Actually, even `rowMeans` errs out for me. BTW - `aggregate(pwgtp15 ~ SEX, DT, mean)` competes with the `DT[...]` call!

Comment: @Parfait With rowMeans I got an error, but after the conversion to numeric that is used in the code, the error disappears.

Comment: @Parfait However, after the conversion, the process is the slowest.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you! I just understood your comment about rowMeans. Thus, the question is just wrong!!!

Comment: Understood. Reach out to your professor on learned knowledge! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, answer choices to the question do not render the same results. There is no named parameter of *by* to [`base::mean()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mean). Since the function allows for *further arguments passed to or from other methods*, it does not error out on *by* argument. Therefore, since it does not split/subset by factors like `DT$SEX`, it would be the fastest time.

Additionally, there are reasons for the other methods returning slower times:

- `tapply(...)`, `sapply(split(...))`, `rowMeans(...)`

  All are direct or indirect *apply* family members which are [hidden loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized) and not fully vectorized computations. Also, `rowMeans` is a wrapper to `apply` and is called twice. Plus, `apply` is infamously known to cast entire data frame/table to matrix where we should heed [@DavidArenburg's caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg):

  > If you are working with `data.frame`s, forget there is a function called `apply`- whatever you do - *don't* use it. *Especially* with a margin of 1 (the only good usecase for this function is to operate over `matrix` columns- margin of 2).
- `mean(...); mean(...)`

  This makes two calls on subsetted data frames. The logical indexing with `[` return **all** columns of data frame, then `$` selects final numeric column for `mean()`.

  In fact, it would be much faster and perhaps ***the fastest*** if you run vector subsets and not data frame subsets that returns all columns:

  ```
  mean(DT$pwgtp15[DT$SEX==1]);mean(DT$pwgtp15[DT$SEX==2])

  a <- Sys.time() 
  DT[,mean(pwgtp15), by=SEX]
  b <- Sys.time() 
  myTime <- b-a
  myTime
  # Time difference of 0.01888704 secs
  # Time difference of 0.03294992 secs
  # Time difference of 0.03321409 secs

  a <- Sys.time() 
  mean(DT$pwgtp15[DT$SEX==1]);mean(DT$pwgtp15[DT$SEX==2])
  b <- Sys.time() 
  myTime <- b-a
  myTime
  # Time difference of 0.006003857 secs
  # Time difference of 0 secs
  # Time difference of 0 secs
  ```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I have a better understanding now. The conclusion is that the question was not properly asked. Or, maybe the professor did it on purpose to make us work harder :)