# Efficiently counting non-NA elements in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sometimes I need to count the number of non-`NA` elements in one or another column in my `data.table`. What is the best `data.table`-tailored way to do so?

For concreteness, let's work with this:

```
DT <- data.table(id = sample(100, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                 var = sample(c(1, 0, NA), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE), key = "id")
```

The first thing that comes to my mind works like this:

```
DT[!is.na(var), N := .N, by = id]
```

But this has the unfortunate shortcoming that `N` does not get assigned to any row where `var` is missing, i.e. `DT[is.na(var), N] = NA`.

So I work around this by appending:

```
DT[!is.na(var), N:= .N, by = id][ , N := max(N, na.rm = TRUE), by = id] #OPTION 1
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best approach; another option I thought of and one suggested by the analog to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986101/counting-non-nas-in-a-data-frame-getting-answer-as-a-vector) question for `data.frame`s would be:

```
DT[ , N := length(var[!is.na(var)]), by = id] # OPTION 2
```

and

```
DT[ , N := sum(!is.na(var)), by = id] # OPTION 3
```

Comparing computation time of these (average over 100 trials), the last seems to be the fastest:

```
OPTION 1 | OPTION 2 | OPTION 3
  .075   |   .065   |   .043
```

Does anyone know a speedier way for `data.table`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the option 3rd seems to be the best one. I've added another one which is valid only if you consider to change the key of your data.table from `id` to `var`, but still option 3 is the fastest on your data.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(id=(1:100)[sample(10,size=1e6,replace=T)],var=c(1,0,NA)[sample(3,size=1e6,replace=T)],key=c("var"))

dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)
dt4 <- copy(dt)

microbenchmark(times=10L,
               dt1[!is.na(var),.N,by=id][,max(N,na.rm=T),by=id],
               dt2[,length(var[!is.na(var)]),by=id],
               dt3[,sum(!is.na(var)),by=id],
               dt4[.(c(1,0)),.N,id,nomatch=0L])
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                         expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  dt1[!is.na(var), .N, by = id][, max(N, na.rm = T), by = id] 95.14981 95.79291 105.18515 100.16742 112.02088 131.87403    10
#                     dt2[, length(var[!is.na(var)]), by = id] 83.17203 85.91365  88.54663  86.93693  89.56223 100.57788    10
#                             dt3[, sum(!is.na(var)), by = id] 45.99405 47.81774  50.65637  49.60966  51.77160  61.92701    10
#                        dt4[.(c(1, 0)), .N, id, nomatch = 0L] 78.50544 80.95087  89.09415  89.47084  96.22914 100.55434    10
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico, have a look at the [Keys and binary search based subsets](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) (and let us know if you find something unclear / to be added [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

Comment: There is another option: `dt5[,.N[!is.na(var)],by=id]` - third fastest on my system and quite a lot better than options 1 and 2.  For some reason option 3 produces binary responses (0,1) instead of counts if more than one 'by' variable is used.  The suggested option 5 gives correct counts.